# UWP NetworkConnectionChanged Event to start and stop a timer

Tags: c#, uwp

I followed some instructions [here](http://windowsapptutorials.com/windows-10/how-to-check-for-network-availability-in-universal-windows-apps/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33144533/uwp-networkconnectionchanged-event) to get this done, but I only get a field which allows me to check the internet connection in my application.

What I would need is to get an event when the connection status has changed throughout the whole application to react on this event.

So I have implemented the singleton class Network Availability from [here](http://windowsapptutorials.com/windows-10/how-to-check-for-network-availability-in-universal-windows-apps/). This works for me to check the connection.

In my application a timer is periodically getting data via http requests.
Now I'd like to stop the timer in case the connection is lost and start the timer in case the connection is back again.

How can I implement the `NetworkStatusChanged Event` in other classes than the `NetworkAvailability` class?

Comment: I think you can just check `NetworkAvailabilty.IsNetworkAvailable` will give you the status of network availability. Based on the http://windowsapptutorials.com/windows-10/how-to-check-for-network-availability-in-universal-windows-apps/

Comment: Yes, of course I could do that, but when you think of the initialisation of the request:
The steps would be:
1) check the connection
2) if connection is succeeded, then get all the http data, else wait for the connection. So I would again need a timer to check the connection every 10s and then I could again start to get the data. 

Would'nt it be easier to have an event rased and then activate all the other timers for the cyclic upodate?

Comment: i have updated the answer to include the event, Pls take a look on that, its a pseudo code i hope it will help.

Comment: yes it helped. I tried to do so and the event came at the right time. I was afraid creating a new custom event, even though there is already such an `NetworkInformationOnNetworkStatusChanged event' in the `NetworkAvailabilty class`

Comment: Glad it worked, happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   //Based on singleton instance,
   if (NetworkAvailabilty.Instance.IsNetworkAvailable)
   {
      GetDataFromHttp();
   }
   else
   {
      //No Internet connection
   }
}
```

You could hook-up event like this.

```
NetworkAvailabilty.Instance
                  .OnNetworkAvailabilityChange += Instance_OnNetworkAvailabilityChange;


void Instance_OnNetworkAvailabilityChange(bool isNetWorkAvailable)
{
       if(isNetWorkAvailable)
          GetData();
}
```